# Single Sign on Authentication and Authorization with RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, single-sign-on

I am using a single sign on authentication method which sits in front of my rails application. Access is denied entirely until signed in to the businesses single sign in service.

I am now wanting to lock some controllers down to a select group of administrators and am wondering what the best way to do this will be.

Should I be creating an administrator controller for managing who has access and then checking the signed in users credentials against this tabl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Comment: that looks like a second authentication platform. I don't want another system for authentication, I just want to focus on authorization.

Comment: CanCan is for authorization, not authentication

Comment: I have had a look at it again. You are right, but it relies on user roles having been set up with the authentication system. I have no control over the session variables provided .

Comment: Actually. At the moment i don't have a 'user' persay. I am using session variables to find out the username of the person 'logged in' to the single sign on session.   But I haven't defined a user model or anything. Im not sure how to implement that.

Comment: actually you have answered my question I am asking a different one now so i will list is separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Declarative Authorization described here:

[Declarative Authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization)

But Cancan is made to be really easier.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

## Authority

Take a look at my new gem, [Authority](https://github.com/nathanl/authority). Its access control is done with plain Ruby methods, so you can use absolutely any logic that you know how to do in Ruby.

### Works fine with Single Sign-On

The situation you describe was the original one we made it for: we already had a SSO app that takes care of the CRUD for creating users and assigning roles, like "Carla is an Administrator in App X; in App Y she is both a Worker and a Salesperson."

When Carla tries to access App Y, if she is signed in, it tells App Y "here is Carla: she's signed in, and she has the following roles." It's then up to App Y to decide what those roles actually let her do. That logic doesn't hit the database at all; we actually compare the role list provided with permissions in a YAML file.

That's just one example of the logic you could implement using Authority, but really it's wide-open.

### Grouping models

In your case, if you used Authority, I'd suggest you group some models under a StandardAuthorizer and others under an AdminAuthorizer. Check out the [README](https://github.com/nathanl/authority) for more explanation.